# Increase length of PyMOL history

Tags: macos, pymol

I am doing some manipulations in MacPyMOL and the standard length of the command line history is too short for my needs.  Does anybody know how to increase it?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal in mac and run pymol like this:

```
 pymol > pymol_history
```

All output will be written to `pymol_history` (no limits)